# Simpler way to check whether or not a sequence is uniformly convergent

Tags: analysis

Let $f_n(x)=(1+x^n)^\frac{1}{n}$ on $[0, \infty)$.

I want to check if this is uniformly convergent.

It's pointwise limit is $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x \text{ if } |x|\geq1\\ 1 \text{ if } |x|<1\\ \end{cases}$$

My first attempt was to use the Weierstrass M-test to check if its uniformly convergent.  I have to do this for two cases $x<1$ and $x \geq 1$.  Setting the derivative equal to zero:

$(x^n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}x^{n-1}-1=0$
$(x^n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}x^{n-1}=1$

At this point I get stuck.  I tried using SageMath to no avail.  I'm wondering if I am approaching this problem correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First notice that $(1+x^n)^{1-\frac{1}{n}} \geq x^{n-1}$ so that $0\leq f_n'(x) \leq 1$ for all $x\in [0,\infty)$. This gives that, for $x\geq 1$,  $f_n'(x)-f'(x)\leq 0$ meaning this difference  is non-increasing so
$$
\sup_{x\in [0,\infty)} |f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq f_n(1)-f(1) = 2^{1/n}-1 \to 0
$$
so the convergence is uniform in $[1,\infty)$. The bound for $f_n'$ and Arzelà-Ascoli give the uniform convergence in $[0,1]$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why $(1+x^n)^{1-\frac{1}{n}}\geq x^{n-1}$ shows that $0\leq f_n'(x)\leq 1$.

Comment: Well $f_n'(x)=\frac{x^{n-1}}{(1+x^n)^{1-\frac{1}{n}}}$.

Comment: Thanks.  I think my first few readings of your solution were quite haphazard as I thought you had somehow showed uniform convergence for all of $[0, \infty)$ simultaneously instead of splitting into cases of $x< 1$ and $x \geq 1$.

Comment: Acutally, one more quick remark, how did you get the derivative of $f'_n(x)$ to be that fraction.  I get the derivative as $(1+x^n)^{\frac{1}{n}-1}x^{n-1}$.  Does it follow changing $\frac{1}{n}-1$ to $1-\frac{1}{n}$?  Why wasn't $x^{n-1}$ changed to $\frac{x^n}{x}$?

Comment: You're right, it follows from changing the exponent. For the second question I guess for convinience, the way I expressed the derivative works best (for me) when getting the desired bounds.